# More info on Conjuncture of Terros (Terras)

Tags: sequences-and-series

In answering a coding problem called "Conjuncture of Terros", there was scant information on the series.

**What is the origin of this series?** and what might applications may use it?

See [original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287909/conjuncture-of-terros/21287964)

```
Terros number sequence
t(0) = n  
t(1) = n  
if t(n-1) is even  
  t(n) = t(n-1)/2  
else  
  t(n) = (3*t(n-1) + 1)/2
```

Web search of "Terros" only led to some ADHD related sites.

[Edit]

@Palec provides a corrected spelling for Riho Terras

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend searching for the Collatz Conjecture (also called 3n+1 problem). It's a more common name. A little explanation though:

You start with natural number $n$. If it's even, you go to $\frac{n}{2}$. If it is odd, you go to $3n+1$, which then will be even of course. Then repeat this process again and again. The Terros sequence is pretty much a modified Collatz sequence, just that you skip the even number $3n+1$ and directy go to $\frac{3n+1}{2}$. The interesting aspect is to find out where this sequence goes in the end. The conjecture states that for any starting point you end up in the circle $1\rightarrow4\rightarrow2\rightarrow1$. However this is not yet proven.

PS: For Terros the circle would of course be $1\rightarrow2\rightarrow1$.

Answer (score 5):

[Riho Terras](http://www.geni.com/people/Riho-Terras/6000000009517751918) (not Terros!) was American mathematician (born 1939 in Tartu, Estonia,  died 2005 in San Diego, CA, USA). Author of Terras Theorem, which is an important partial result in solving [Collatz Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CollatzProblem.html), known also as 3n + 1 conjecture.

The conjecture is that given a positive integer $a_0$, iterating

$$
a_n = \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{2} a_{n-1} & \text{for } a_{n-1} \text{ even,} \\
  3 a_{n-1} + 1 & \text{for } a_{n-1} \text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$$

always reaches 1.

[Terras Theorem](http://www.ericr.nl/wondrous/terras.html) uses a slight modification $t_n$ of the original Collatz sequence $a_n$. It says that for almost all $t_0$ holds that $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}: t_n < t_0$ for $t_n$ defined as

$$
t_n = \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{2} t_{n-1} & \text{for } t_{n-1} \text{ even,} \\
  \frac{1}{2} (3 t_{n-1} + 1) & \text{for } t_{n-1} \text{ odd.}
\end{cases}
$$

They are equivalent from the convergence point of view because $t_n$ is subsequence of $a_n$ obtained by deletion of values immediately following an odd value. These deleted values are always even, because the preceding value is odd and

$$
\forall k \in \mathbb{N}: 3(2k + 1) + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{2}.
$$

When this is so much on-topic, I cannot help:

[image: Collatz Conjecture]